# gzip Python3 Can't Convert Bytes to String

Tags: python

I have a function unzip written in Python2.7

```
def unzip(text):
    try:
        return gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(text)).read()
    except IOError:
        return text
```

When ran with Python3.7, I'm getting an error

```
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

I tried

changing it to `return gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=bytes(text, 'utf-8')).read()`

But then I got: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 2):

`StringIO` produces string (`str`) objects and need to be encoded/decoded accordingly. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o.

In your case given that you are dealing with binary data you need to use `BytesIO`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o.

You cannot use `bytes` directly, as `GzipFile` expects a file-like object with a `read` method.

The reason why your code works in python 2 and not in python 3 is because `bytes` and `str` are the same in python 2. If you have code that needs to work in both versions, then you may need to use the `BytesIO` class from the `io` module. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#binary-i-o.

Comment: I think you meant (emphasis added): "If you have code that needs to work in both versions, then you may need to use the *BytesIO* class from the `io` module." `GzipFile` expects a binary mode file-like object in both cases; `io.BytesIO` would work in both cases.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger I fixed the answer

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the insight but in my snippet `text` is a string. Changing to `BytesIO` didn't work since `BytesIO(text)` required that `text` be a byte-like object.

Comment: Actually from your post I was able to figure out what was going on. I got it working by doing the following: `return gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(bytes(text, "utf-8"))).read()`